# Tableau: sort month on fiscal or calendar year parameter

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I have added a parameter to select either fiscal or calendar year. I have a year over year line graph and since the fiscal year begins in July I would like July to be the first month listed on the axis when fiscal year is selected.  Right now the months display January to December.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the fiscal year by changing the `fiscal year start` to `June`

Check below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Fiscal dates in Tableau](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/fiscal-dates-in-tableau/) are best managed using standard date functions. In this case your fiscal date would be a DATEADD of 7 months: DATEADD('month',7,[Order Date])